# Internal links inside div overflow: hidden

Tags: overflow, hidden, sidebar

Hello I would like to make a `overflow: hidden` div that contains all my sections in my one-page design. Like http://www.nathanieldeal.com
Can anyone help me. Also if you have a better idea instead of `calc(100% - 50px)` by the way, the sidebar is `50px`.

Comment: I think what you want to do is make it so that the website does not give the vertical scrollbar. You want it so that the only way to reach the other "pages" of your one-page design is to click on the links on the sidebar. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `overflow:hidden` on the body tag.

CSS:

```
body {
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: What if one of the divs have more height than 100%?

Comment: @JensKvist What do you want to happen in this situation?